# Prove $ \sin\ (\alpha'+\beta'+\gamma')\cos\ \beta \geq \sin\ \alpha' \cos\ \gamma+ \sin\ (\beta'+ \gamma')\cos\ (\alpha+\beta )$

Tags: inequality

${\bf Question}$ : Let $$ 0< \alpha,\ \beta,\ \gamma,\ \alpha + \beta
+  \gamma \leq \pi,\ \alpha':=r\alpha,\ \beta':=r\beta,\
\gamma':=r\gamma,\ 0< r< 1
$$
Prove $$  \sin\ (\alpha'+\beta'+\gamma')\cos\ \beta \geq \sin\
\alpha' \cos\ \gamma+ \sin\ (\beta'+ \gamma')\cos\ (\alpha+\beta )$$

(I can not convince that this is true)

${\bf Proof}$ : Let $$T(r):=
 \sin\ (\alpha'+\beta'+\gamma')\cos\ \beta -\bigg\{ \sin\
\alpha' \cos\ \gamma+ \sin\ (\beta'+ \gamma')\cos\ (\alpha+\beta )
\bigg\}$$

With Cosine and Sine Laws (Long computation), we have

$$ T(r) =\bigg\{
\sin\ (\alpha'+\beta')\cos\ \gamma' +\cos\ (\alpha'+\beta')\sin\
\gamma' \bigg\} \cos\ \beta $$ $$-\bigg\{ \sin\ \alpha' \cos\
\gamma+ [\sin\ \beta' \cos\ \gamma' +\cos\ \beta'\sin\ \gamma']\cos\
(\alpha+\beta ) \bigg\}$$

$$=
(\cos\ \alpha'-\cos\ \alpha) \sin\ (\beta' + \gamma' ) \cos\ \beta +
\cos\
 (\beta' + \gamma' ) \sin\ \alpha'\cos\ \beta  +\sin\ ( \beta' + \gamma' )\sin\
\alpha\sin\ \beta- \sin\ \alpha' \cos\ \gamma
$$

$$\geq
\sin\ \alpha'\cos\
 (\beta' + \gamma' - \beta ) - \sin\ \alpha' \cos\ \gamma
$$

If $\beta' + \gamma' - \beta  \geq 0$ then $$ \beta' + \gamma' -
\beta \leq \gamma,\ T(r)\geq 0
$$

The other case is not solved. But the case where $r=\frac{1}{5},\
\alpha=\frac{\pi}{3},\ \beta =\frac{\pi}{2},\ \gamma = \frac{\pi}{6}
$ is satisfied. How can we prove the remaining case ?

Comment: it is not true. $r=0.5,\alpha + \beta + \gamma = \pi，\implies \cos\ \beta \geq 0 $

Comment: Note that $$ \cos\ \beta\geq (\sin\ \alpha'-\cos\ \alpha')\cos\
\gamma $$ Not true is not clear.

Comment: ya, let $\gamma=0,\alpha + \beta  = \pi,\cos\ \beta=-\cos\ \alpha,-\cos\ 2\alpha' \ge \sin\ \alpha'-\cos\ \alpha' \implies \sin\ \alpha'-\cos\ \alpha' \ge 0 \implies \alpha' \ge \dfrac{\pi}{4}$